# HTML2PDF : error (sometimes) when generating, but PDF generated

Tags: magento2, html2pdf

Let me explain !

I have a magento website. I'm generating custom PDF when my user is making an order.

It works most of the time, but for some reason, sometimes, I have this error :

> Undefined property: Spipu\Html2Pdf\MyPdf::$h in ...../vendor/spipu/html2pdf/src/MyPdf.php on line 670"

The line is this :

```
public function getH()
{
    return $this->h;
}
```

The class is : **class MyPdf extends \TCPDF**
and in TCPDF, $**h is a protected variable**

It's weird, knowing that my PDF is saved on my server, and I can open without getting an error..

Do you have any idea of what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ah got it !

Forgot to mention, i'm using a loop to make and attach my pdf to a mailer.

I had to put the declaration of the HTML2PDF inside the loop, not outside (that's make sense).

Hope this will help !